# python error need explanations

Tags: python, operators

I have this error when running the following program and I don't understand why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 18

main()   line 13, in main

nombre=condition(nombre)  
line 3, in condition
if (nombre % 2) == 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Here is my program:

```
def condition(nombre):
   if (nombre % 2) == 1:
      nombre=(nombre*3)+1
   else:
      nombre=(nombre/2)


def main():
  nombre=int(input())
  print(nombre)
  while nombre!=1:
    nombre=condition(nombre)
  print(nombre)



main()
```

Comment: You forgot to do `return nombre` at the end of your `condition` function, so it returns the default value of `None`. BTW, you should use `//` for that division.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It would be on the second iteration of the `while` loop

Comment: @TomSitter I didn't see the loop. xD. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you should indent the `print(nombre)` so that it's inside the `while` loop.

Comment: i've just done 'return nombre' in my 'condition' function and it worked but i still don't understand why it wasn't working and why the 'return' command changed this...                                                                                                                        [edit] just got it, thanks guys

Comment: oops true @PM2Ring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurring because you doest returning value from condition function and in second iteration of your while != 1 value of nombre was equal to def. try this to fix your code:

```
def condition(nombre):
   if (nombre % 2) == 1:
      nombre=(nombre*3)+1
   else:
      nombre=(nombre/2)
   return nombre
```

if you want that condition return integer value you should use // instead of / :

```
def condition(nombre):
   if (nombre % 2) == 1:
      nombre=(nombre*3)+1
   else:
      nombre=(nombre//2)
   return nombre
```

Comment: You’re welcome. You can flag this answer as a answer. it would be good for me

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NoneType` from `condition` function since it doesn't return anything.